# Header doesn't fill wrapper element in IE 10

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-10

I have a sticky header on my website (built with wordpress and a sitebuilder plugin called elementor) that works great on firefox, chrome and edge, but not on internet explorer 10 and 11. when the window width becomes smaller than 768px, the header doesn't fill its wrapper element.

I have tried searching for solutions on google, but most of the threads with similar issues seem to be about flexbox which I believe is unrelated to this bug (since neither the wrapper or the header elements are set to "display: flex" in my case).

I tried to copy the html and css into a codepen but it didn't work. However
I created a loom to illustrate the issue. https://www.useloom.com/share/093eac76c2ff424fa55bbca1b5c3234c. Here is the site url: https://figgesresa.se/

The wrapper element "elementor-section-wrap" has "width: auto" applied to it, while its child (that becomes to small below 768px) has no width style applied to it. I have tried adding "width: 100%" to it, but it doesn't make a difference.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since it's a plugin that's causing the issue I'd advise asking the developers if they can shed any light on the issue. However, a quick Google search found that [they don't support legacy browsers](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/elementor-issue-with-edge-explorer/) anyway.

Comment: It's odd considering they mention "In any case, pages built with Elementor will show up in all the browsers." on their requirements page (https://docs.elementor.com/article/38-requirements).

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether you have add the "width: 100%" css style for the "elementor-section-wrap" element first child (the header, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdOyz.png)), you could also try to use "!important" keyword to prevent other css style override this  property.